# SQLMembershipProvider stored procedure being ran twice

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, sitecore

So I've recently been working on modifying the MembershipProvider Sitecore uses, or SqlMembershipProvider. Microsoft released their source code, so I copied it all and added some minor things such as password history etc. Everything seemed to be working great until I ran into this strange bug.

Basically I added code to the Login_OnClick event of the login page so that if a user has reset their password and been assigned an auto generated one it redirects them to the Change Password page.

The code calls Membership.ValidateUser which in turn calls CheckPassword. If their password is wrong or they have previous failed password attempts a stored procedure "dbo.aspnet_Membership_UpdateUserInfo" is called to update the relevant variables (such as FailedPasswordAttemptCount). ValidateUser and CheckPassword are included methods in the SqlMembershipProvider and were unmodified by me.

The weirdness is that the same code works correctly on a coworkers computer, but on mine it was running the stored procedure twice. The only way I was able to get it to stop doing that was to remove this code from my Login_OnClick method but I have no idea why that fixes it, nor why it works on my coworkers computer.

Here is the offending code... any ideas?

```
protected void Login_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = ((TextBox) Login.FindControl("UserName")).Text;
            string password = ((TextBox) Login.FindControl("Password")).Text;
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlConnectionHolder holder = null;
                    SqlDataReader reader = null;
                    try
                    {
                        var _sqlConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["core"].ConnectionString;
                        holder = SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(_sqlConnectionString, true);

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM dbo.PasswordReset WHERE " +
                                                        "username=@username",
                                                        holder.Connection);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

                        int count = 0;
                        using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }

                        //results were found in the password reset table so redirect them to the change password page
                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("/sitecore/login/changepassword.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (holder != null)
                        {
                            holder.Close();
                            holder = null;
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Update: So after testing we found out that the bug only happens when you include the domain in the username. As in, sitecore/admin does not work correctly, but admin does. I also found out it's definitely not my code that is the issue because when I plug in the default source code to SQLMembershipProvider I still get the same error. A default fresh install of Sitecore works properly however, even though it's still using SQLMembershipProvider.

So I'm still kind of lost, but obviously there is something different about the SQLMembershipProvider compiled from the source and the default SQLMembershipProvider sitecore uses.

Comment: stupid question - are you sure you aren't double-clicking the button?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I wish it was that simple!